# Replace " " of a string with "%20" - Complexity issue, which of the two below mentioned should be preferred?

Tags: java, string

1. Converting it to char array and then concatenating it back replacing spaces with "%20".

OR

2. Dividing string into substrings with "white space" as the "separator" and just combining the strings with "%20" between them.

For eg:

```
Str = "This is John Shaw   "
```

(There are as many extra spaces at the end as there are spaces in the string)

expected outcome:

```
"This%20is%20John%20Shaw"
```

Comment: `foo.replace(" ", "%20")` but as that sounds like you want to encode a URL, maybe you actually might want to use URLEncode: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Having a example would be nice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `URLEncoder` conwert witespace into `+`

Comment: @talex: I know but if Type_Caster *really* wants to encode a URL that is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not this ?

```
txt = txt.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Let me know if I understood it wrong.

Comment: Kindly, read it again! The content and question was changed from what I had posted earlier...

Comment: `replaceAll` is nothing to do here (you don't use regex), use `replace`

Answer (score 0):

By replaceAll method of the String class as follow.

```
String str = "This is John Shaw ";
str = str.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

**Output**

This%20is%20John%20Shaw%20

Comment: (the same as for @faheemfarhan's answer) `replaceAll` is nothing to do here (you don't use regex), use `replace`

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Where you are sitting? How it doesn't work? It works as expected and required.

Comment: Yes, it will work as expected, but you really don't need here regular expression, which is accepted by `replaceAll` and just `replace` is  enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can write both algorithms with a complexity O(n) where n is the number of characters in the String but there are much better algorithms to do that.
By the way I wrote an example that show you the computing time, one method is faster than the other but they are both, as I said, O(n)

```
public class ComplexityTester
{
    //FIRST METHOD
    public static String replaceSpacesArray(String str)
    {
        str = str.trim(); // leading and trailing whitespaces omitted

        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

        String result = "";

        for(int i = 0; i<charArray.length; i++) // it replaces spaces with %20
        {
            if(charArray[i] == ' ') //it's a space, replace it!
            result += "%20";        
            else                    //it's not a space, add it! 
            result += charArray[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

    //SECOND METHOD
    public static String replaceSpacesWithSubstrings(String str)
    {
        str = str.trim(); // leading and trailing whitespaces omitted

        String[] words = new String[5]; //array of strings, to add substrings
        int wordsSize = 0;              //strings in the array


        //From the string to an array of substrings 
        //(the words separated by spaces of the string)
        int indexFrom = 0;              
        int indexTo = 1;

        while(indexTo<=str.length())
        {
            if(wordsSize == words.length) //if the array is full, resize it!
            words = resize(words);

            //we reach the end of the sting, add the last word to the array!
            if(indexTo == str.length()) 
            {
                words[wordsSize++] = str.substring(indexFrom, indexTo++);
            }
            else if(str.substring(indexTo-1,indexTo).equals(" "))//it's a space
            {
                //we add the last word to the array
                words[wordsSize++] = str.substring(indexFrom, indexTo-1); 

                indexFrom = indexTo; //update the indices
                indexTo++;
            }
            else //it's a character not equal to space
            {
                indexTo++;  //update the index
            }
        }

        String result = "";

        // From the array to the result string
        for(int i = 0; i<wordsSize; i++)
        {
            result += words[i];

            if(i+1!=wordsSize) 
            result += "%20";
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String[] resize(String[] array) 
    {
        int newLength = array.length*2;

        String[] newArray = new String[newLength];

        System.arraycopy(array,0,newArray,0,array.length);

        return newArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String example = "The Java Tutorials are practical guides "
        +"for programmers who want to use the Java programming " 
        +"language to create applications. They include hundreds " 
        +"of complete, working examples, and dozens of lessons. " 
        +"Groups of related lessons are organized into \"trails\"";

        String testString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) //String 'testString' is string 'example' repeted 100 times
        {
            testString+=example;
        }

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        replaceSpacesArray(testString); 
        System.out.println("COMPUTING TIME (ARRAY METHOD) = " 
                              + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time));

        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        replaceSpacesWithSubstrings(testString);
        System.out.println("COMPUTING TIME (SUBSTRINGS METHOD) = "
                                + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
    }
}
```